# How do i send real time cloud watch events to SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services

i have some real-time cloud watch events in log group and i want to filter them for specific KEYWORD and send it to SQS and i don't want to use lambda and kinesis,
since the logs are real-time and getting created every second i don't want to use lambda and kinesis.

I don't see ant option in Cloud watch to send logs to SQS

Answer (score 0):

Amazon CloudWatch **cannot send events to an Amazon SQS queue**.

The available destinations are:

- Amazon OpenSearch Service
- Amazon Kinesis
- Amazon Data Firehose
- AWS Lambda

[image: CloudWatch subscription filters]